# unsupported protocol scheme while creating ec2 Security group

Tags: go, goamz

I am trying to create security group using goamz.
Below is my code.

```
package main
import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "github.com/mitchellh/goamz/aws"
    "github.com/mitchellh/goamz/ec2"
)
type SecurityGroup struct {
    Id string `xml:"groupId"`   
    Name string `xml:"groupName"` 
    Description string `xml:"groupDescription"`
    VpcId string `xml:"vpcId"`
}

func main() {
    auth := aws.Auth{
        AccessKey: os.Getenv("key"),
        SecretKey: os.Getenv("secret"),
    }
    region := aws.Region{
        Name : "us-east-1",
    }
    ec2conn := ec2.New(auth, region)
    fmt.Printf("%+v\n", ec2conn)
    resp, err := ec2conn.CreateSecurityGroup(ec2.SecurityGroup{Name: "testing12", 
                                          Description: "testing123", VpcId: "vpc-123456"})
    fmt.Printf("%+v\n", resp)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("%s\n", err.Error())
    }
}
```

And I get the below Response upon execution.
    `<nil>`
    `Get /? XXXXXXXXX`
    `unsupported protocol scheme ""`
I am not sure whether we use any protocol explicitly to create.
Please help me understanding this.

Comment: I don't use goamz so I can't verify for sure, but from [docs](http://godoc.org/github.com/mitchellh/goamz/aws#Region), I think you need to use `aws.Regions["us-east-1"]`. You're initializing a `Region` struct without setting any endpoint URLs, hence the error.

Comment: @twotwotwo let me try this..

Comment: @twotwotwo is correct, you must assign more than just the `Name` property on the `s3.Region` struct. i.e. `region := aws.Regions["us-east-1"]` or alternatively `region := aws.USEAST`. These region structs are already predefined by the aws package.